# Change emacs org-mode key binding for code block

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode I use `<s` then **TAB** to insert a code block. This action will insert a code block like

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC
    .
    .
    .
 #+END_SRC
```

but I want to modify this action to insert something like

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python -n :results output pp replace :exports both
    .
    .
    .
#+END_SRC
```

I know it's possible to change default behaviour of `:result` or `:exports` in emacs init file but I prefer to change this shortcut behaviour, because it makes me able to change the options in line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question based on [legoscia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113848/legoscia)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53414536/5737318).

As mentioned in the [Easy Templates section of the org-mode manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Easy-templates.html), you can modify these templates by customizing the variable `org-structure-template-alist`. Using `M-x customize-option` and applying changes will add all easy templates to your `init` file, if you don't like it you can add just one line to your `init` file to change a template or add one.

In my case I added this line to my emacs `init` file to add `<p` then **TAB** :

```
(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist '("p" "#+BEGIN_SRC python -n :results output pp replace :exports both\n?\n#+END_SRC"))
```

ALL CREDITS GOES TO [legoscia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113848/legoscia)

Answer (score 2):

As of Org 9.2 the method employed  by @shae128 is no longer valid. Instead you'll need to use tempo-define-template, like this:

```
(tempo-define-template "python-block"
           '("#+begin_src python :results raw output"
             n n p n n
             "#+end_src")
           "<p"
           "Insert an outputting Python block"
           'org-tempo-tags)
```

`n` stands for newline, `p` for where to leave the mark, `<p` for the command to expand from when hitting tab.

Thanks to [Omar's answer here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51384/config-easy-template-src-code-in-0rg-9-2/51411#51411)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the Easy Templates section of the org-mode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html), you can modify these templates by customizing the variable `org-structure-template-alist`.  (Use `M-x customize-option`.)

For `<s`, the default expansion is `"#+BEGIN_SRC ?\n\n#+END_SRC"`.  You can just edit it to include the options you want after `BEGIN_SRC`.  Alternatively, you could add a new template, e.g. `<p`, that expands to the text you want.

Comment: Thank you, your answer solved my problem, but as it adds all easy template's config to init file I will add another answer based on your answer which will keep init file more readable by adding just one line for new or edited easy template. ALL CREDITS GOES TO @legoscia